# Characterize the orthogonal matrices that map a given vector to $e_1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an input vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, consider the set of matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with the properties:

1. $M$ is orthogonal (so $MM^T = I$)
2. $Mv = \langle 1, 0, 0, \dots, 0 \rangle$.

Now define a set $S = ${$m$  | $m$ is the first row of a matrix $M$ that satisfies the above properties} $\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.  I am interested in characterizing $S$.

Clearly, for any $m \in S$, we have $m \cdot v = 1$.  But in exactly what way is the orthogonality condition restrictive?

Comment: The equation $MM^T$ says that $M^T$ is the inverse of $M$. So, given that $Mv = e_1$, we get that $M^T e_1 = $...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r_i$ be the rows of $M$. (2) translates to $r_i \cdot v = \delta_{1,i}$, so in particular $r_2, \ldots, r_n$ are in $v^\perp$ (the orthogonal complement of $v$). Since evidently $v \neq 0$, we have $\dim v^\perp = n-1$, so in fact $r_2, \ldots, r_n$ span $v^\perp$ since they are orthogonal. But since $r_1$ is orthogonal to them, it follows that $r_1$ must actually be parallel to $v$. That is, $r_1 \cdot v = \pm |r_1||v| = \pm |v| = 1$. Now $v = r_1$ is a unit vector is the only way for this to have a solution, so $|S| = 0$ or $1$ depending on whether or not $v$ is a unit vector.

(To get existence if $|v| = 1$, use the Gram-Schmidt process on $v^\perp$ and set $r_1 = v$.)

Comment: This is old, but I had to say that this is overcomplicated, and I seem to have misunderstood what you meant by S (or it got edited). Your conditions immediately say m=v, which almost instantly says S = the unit sphere.